# Merge dataframes and pick the latest record

Tags: apache-spark, join, merge, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have 2 dataframes.

**df1:**

```
|Timestamp                        |ProjectId|AusID|Version|
+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|2017-09-19 16:57:36.000642 +02:00|20034    |529  |2017   |
|2017-09-19 16:58:32.000642 +02:00|20035    |973  |2017   |
|2017-09-21 12:51:36.000642 +02:00|20034    |521  |2017   |
|2017-09-22 17:58:36.000642 +02:00|20035    |543  |2017   |
```

**df2:**

```
|Timestamp                        |ProjectId|AusID|Version|
+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|2017-09-20 08:46:17.465000 Z     |20034    |513  |2017   |
|2017-09-20 08:46:17.465000 Z     |20035    |973  |2017   |
|2017-09-21 08:46:17.465000 Z     |20034    |521  |2017   |
|2017-09-22 08:46:17.465000 Z     |20035    |587  |2017   |
```

These records are in millions with few more columns. I want to merge both dataframes and remove duplicates using **AusID**, i.e. when 2 records have same AusID, pick the latest one (on the basis of date) and remove the other one. The other problem is, dates are also in different format in both **data frames**.

I tried using the follwing approach:

```
df1.union(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2)).show()
```

but it seems, it is considering all the columns. It would be great if someone can give some hint.

Comment: Union the two dataframes and use window function and to group and select the latest timestamp.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala The data size is in several 100 GBs. Would it be a good idea to union all the records?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Union operation does not shuffle the data. So, we need not worry about performance.

Comment: ok. I will look into window function and union. Thanks.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian does window function or oder by do shuffle?

Answer (score 3):

You can consider following approach:

```
result = df1.unionAll(df2)
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ProjectId","AusID","Version").orderBy(col("Timestamp").asc)
val latestForEachKey = result.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")
latestForEachKey.show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks. do we have to partition by all the columns except date?

Comment: Yes.. We have to partition by all the columns except date.

Comment: Can I ask the intuition behind this?

Comment: Is any of the operation above do shuffle?

Comment: No..There is no shuffle

Comment: but in spark ui, i can see there is one shuffledRDD. I dont know where from it comes.